# Google analytics how to track subdomains

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to track subdomains in google analytics tool. But I didn't found setting to on subdomain tracking under admin->tracking info

Answer (score 0):

Subdomain tracking can be set up in how you specify your root domain when you create the tracker object:

```
ga('create','UA-XXXXX-Y', 'domain.com');
```

for example, will track domain.com as well as its subdomains.

According to this link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain

> Tracking users across subdomains does not require any additional
>   configuration.